# How to resolve SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0?

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error, jsonparser, unexpected-token

I'm getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0** upon trying to fetch the authorization info stored against the key "auth" in the local storage.

Additinal Info: The value stored against the key "auth" is basically an object of key value pairs.

Here is the code:

```
public async getAuthInfo(): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
const authInfo = <string>(<any>browser.executeScript("return localStorage.getItem('auth');"));
if (!authInfo) {
  throw { error: 'No authorization details found in local storage.' };
}
try {
  return JSON.parse(authInfo);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
}
}

const authInfo = await this.getAuthInfo();
this.httpService.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authInfo.accessToken}`;
```

authInfo value looks something like this

```
"{\"accessToken\":\"yuiooy\",\"authenticated\":true,\"sessionAcquired\":true}"
```

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Double check what the value of `authInfo` is. It sounds like it isn't valid JSON and actually starts with an `M` instead

Comment: @phuzi I have updated the my question with some information about the authInfo value. Please take a look

Comment: Can you confirm the content on `authInfo` because that doesn't match the error you're seeing!

Comment: @phuzi please have a look at the updated description. Also, what do you mean by content on authInfo?

Comment: perhaps you could show the code where you have `localStorage.setItem('auth', ...)` so we explicity see what authInfo is supposed to be

Comment: What @phuzi means is that `authInfo` does *not* look like `{ accessToken: value, expiry: value }` because that wouldn't produce the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M". That error means that the input to `JSON.parse` begins with the character `M`, so whatever input you're actually using starts with an `M`.

Comment: @apsillers You are right, My authInfo looks like                                                                                          
"{\"accessToken\":\"yuiooy\",\"authenticated\":true,\"sessionAcquired\":true}"

Comment: `JSON.parse("{\"accessToken\":\"yuiooy\",\"authenticated\":true,\"sessionAcquired\":true}")` does not produce the error described, so based on the information you've presented so far, the question isn't answerable, unfortunately. If you can provide an example that does produce the error, you can edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, it worked for me

```
public async getAuthInfo(): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
const authInfo = <any>browser.executeScript("return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));");
if (!authInfo) { throw {error : 'No authorization details found in local storage.'};}
return authInfo;
```

}